# JSF PrimeFaces 3.5 FileUpload local path

Tags: file, jsf, primefaces, filepath

I am using PrimeFaces 3.5 and am processing uploaded PDF files using p:fileUpload.
I want to provide a link within my app to launch the PDF file on the local machine that the end user has just chosen to upload to the server.

I know the server should not care about the local path of files the end user uploads to the server.  However, the end user wants to verify they uploaded the correct files via links on the upload screen itself.  The slow way is to link to the now uploaded copy on the server.  I would much rather launch their local original file from their own machine to avoid downloading a potentially large file that they just waited to upload.  But that means a JavaScript object or the server must know the full local path for each file uploaded.  I am still new to JSF and was able to do this with no problem in the old system (Java swing with a signed applet).

If forced to link to the server copy, it may appear as a degradation of performance in the new system.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in JavaScript only possible if the browser supports the new HTML5 `File` API. The only alternative would be to use an Applet or JWS, as you figured out.

JSF is not relevant as it is in the context of this question merely a HTML code generator.

Comment: Since our client has a strange affinity for IE and I cannot force any browser, I will just have to do as I feared and link to the copy on the server as the lowest common denominator.  Thanks.